# Solr - Add timestamp of last dih import to search ui

Tags: asp.net, ajax, solr, lucene, dih

*So this post was going to have more links but it's my first post and apparntly you need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links so... sorry about that*

**The Problem**
I'm currently working on building new search interfaces for my company using Solr 5.1.3. My boss has asked me if there is anyway we can display the time stamp of the last successful delta import as part of the ui. The idea being that it would be an easy way to quickly diagnose if the delta imports have been failing.

**My Architecture**
My search page is in ASP.NET MVC5. I'm using the [ajax-solr](https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr) library which allows most of the work to be done client-side. Our Solr instance is running on it's own separate Linux server. The data is stored in a MS SQL server database

Currently delta imports are handled via crontab which calls a wget with the Solr URL to trigger a delta import. (I should mention I'm using the somewhat non-standard [DeltaQueryViaFullImport](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerDeltaQueryViaFullImport) method to perform delta imports).

**What I've tried so far**
I know that after each import wget will save a copy of Solr's response XML (which includes the time-stamp I'm after) to the linux box in the appropriate core's directory. But, I haven't been able to find a way to get that info to the UI of ASP.NET page.

Before posting I found two other SO posts (sorry no I link for reasons at top) that pointed me to the LukeRequestHandler which can access some value for each core called "lastModified". Is this the same as the time of the last import? If not, is there perhaps some query that can be given to solr to get the time-stamp of the last import?